# Posting a link for Google Maps

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

Is it policy not to show links in a question?

The number of questions asked about Google Maps without a link to a map is large. An actual map can show show the problem and help debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links are certainly allowed in posts. Users with less than 10 reputation are restricted to posting at most 2 links per question or answer, but other than that... there are no particular limits so long as the links are relevant.

If folks wanted to add a link to a map, they can certainly do so.

Comment: Maybe they just don't know how to get the link out of Google Maps.. :)

Comment: @Benjol That's entirely possible, and I couldn't blame them. I have to figure out how to do it all over again every time I need to link to a map. :)

Comment: The problem is that in many of questions a definative answer cannot be given without access to to a live map.

Comment: @davidstrachan I can appreciate that. My point is that we don't do anything to stop anyone from linking to their maps.